# Can you freeze fruit pies after baking - Will this ruin them?

Tags: freezing, pie

I was thinking about apple, but would apply to any fruit.

Answer (score 7):

I've done this both ways and prefer to freeze my fruit pies before I bake them.  You have to bake them longer (20 min to 1/2 hour) and will need to use foil to be sure the crust doesn't come out too dark. No soggy crust this way.

Comment: this has the advantage of not getting your kitchen hot in the summer. In the winter when you want the pie, a little electric heat will probably be more than welcome

Answer (score 3):

You can certainly freeze them.  You can also freeze component parts.  I've frozen balls of pie crust and re-used later - my crust is butter based, so it is easier to work with when cold (just thawed, for example).  I have 7 containers of peach filling (I don't like spices in most fruit pies, so it is just peaches, sugar, and some of the juices from the peaches) in my freezer.  When I take it out, I will thaw, add instant tapioca pearls, and bake.  If I have room in my freezer come apple season (which I probably won't), I'll probably freeze apple slices as well.

You could also, if you liked, par bake your crust to get it more ready for baking and freeze in a pie plate, then throw everything else in, add a top crust, and go when you are ready to eat.

Answer (score 2):

You can certainly freeze them, I do it all the time.

Let them cool to room temperature on the counter.

Seal them well, I tend to use good plastic freezer bags and use a straw to suck the air out.

Don't stack them until they are frozen solid.

Nice to eat later in the winter, when there is snow around and have a little taste of summer/fall.  (I tend to do several peach and several apple.)

Comment: How do you thaw them? I've had pies get soggy even when moving from fridge-counter. I imagine this would be worse when the pie is much colder. Any tips? I hate soggy pie crust.

Comment: @Adam - what about baking them from frozen using foil to keep the top crust from getting too brown.  There are also a few tips when preparing a pie to help keep the bottom crust from getting soggy.  Personally I brush my bottom crust with egg white before putting the filling in and move it into the oven as fast as possible after the filling touches crust.

Comment: I've frozen the raw crust, then lined the crust with plastic wrap, filled it with fruit, and frozen the whole thing in a tin. You can pop the fruit out, bake the crust in the oven and once the fruit thaws, add back into the shell and bake as usual.

Comment: @Adam - the bottom crust can get a little soggy.  I tend to then re-heat the pie (I like warm pie...) and after some ice cream, could not tell the difference anyways.

Comment: some people hate the bottom crust being soggy, especially those of us who don't put ice cream on our pies.  Rose Levy Branbaum hates soggy bottom crust so much she makes her pies with a top crust only.

Answer (score 0):

I brown the lower crust put in my home grown apricot filling top the pie with unbaked crust then freeze. Later in the year I pull one out , let it thaw and bake as normal. Perfect, I am eating a hot pc. with ice cream right now!